# df.loc values in new dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to find average values within a certain range and add them to a new dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = y.loc[y['a'].between(0.0, 0.05), 'b'].mean()
```

However, the dataframe only shows the column names and has 0 rows, why is that?

Comment: Can you provide test data set too?

Answer (score 0):

Working for me. I created a dummy dataset

```py
 y = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,0,0.1,0.2,0.5,100]})
```

and then

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame()                                                    

In [11]: df                                                                     
Out[11]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

In [12]: df['x'] = y.loc[y['a'].between(0.0,0.5)].mean()                        

In [13]: df                                                                     
Out[13]: 
     x
a  0.2
```

This means that in your dataset, there is no value that lies between 0.0 and 0.05.

Comment: If I only run the function seperately I get the value that I want in the console, but when I try to also assign it to a dataframe it doesn't show the value in that dataframe, that's my problem.

Comment: Show us your `a` and `b` columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what is 'b' in your code. Are you using MultiIndexing? If not, just delete this part inside loc and should be fine

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = y.loc[y['a'].between(0.0, 0.05)].mean()
```